# How to edit a target path of a shortcut in c# with multiple references

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007, shortcut

I am creating a shortcut using WshShell VS2010 .Net 4 and ant to be able to create a target path that has a reference to AccessRuntinme then our application. This is what I have so far with no errors untill I run the program and click the button.

```
 private void CreateShortCut64()
    {
        object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
        WshShell shell = new WshShell();
        string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\LinkName.lnk";
        IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
        string targetPath64 = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\MSACCESS.EXE\" \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Program\\Prog.accdr\"";
        shortcut.Description = "Program";
        shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+A";
        shortcut.TargetPath = targetPath64;
        shortcut.IconLocation = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Program\\" + @"\Prog.ico";
        shortcut.Save();
    }
```

The above example works fine if I leave out the reference to Access Runtime and just have My Program as the target but I want to have both in the target which works fine when you edit the target through windows.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that it is because you are not setting MS Access to run-time mode:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" /runtime "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Prog.accdr"
```

Edit re comments

```
shortcut.TargetPath = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\MSACCESS.EXE\";
shortcut.Arguments = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Program\\Prog.accdr\" /runtime";
```

I tested with MS Access 2010 x64 installed, so the path names are different, otherwise the code is pretty similar to the OP.

```
object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
WshShell shell = new WshShell();
string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\LinkName.lnk";
IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
shortcut.Description = "Program";
shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+A";
shortcut.TargetPath = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\MSACCESS.EXE\"";
shortcut.Arguments = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\My Program\\Prog.accdr\"  /runtime";
shortcut.IconLocation = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Abtrac\\" + @"\Prog.ico";
shortcut.Save();
```

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work unfortunately. I think the problem is with the target having more than one value being set as I can set it to either "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" or "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\Prog.accdr" but not the two combined (with or without /runtime added).

Comment: If you try to run an accdr in a shortcut without the /runtime switch, you will get an error. I created a desktop shortcut and tested.

Comment: This is a target for my program that I created from the Accdr not the c# program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Prog\Prog.accdr" /runtime and this works fine

Comment: I have added a note, tested in c#.

Comment: Hi Remou, you have tested or will be testing? Thanks for your help

Comment: I tested your code plus the changes noted in c# at the time posted above and it worked for me. The shortcut was created and opened the specified file with a security warning.

Comment: Hi Remou, Is there any chance you could please post your code for me thanks? What was the warning that you had? Thanks for taking the time to test this for me.

Comment: The code is the same as yours, I originally posted the only part that was in any way different. I have now posted the active code. The warning is not a code warning, it is a windows security warning about opening an unknown Access database.

Comment: The sample has also worked for me. The problem I had in my code was missing the shortcut.Arguments line. Thanks for all your help.